# Azure AD - enable the service principal as a an application administrator

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I'd like to know how to have a **ServicePrincipal in Azure AD** that will be able to **alter app registrations that it doesn't own**, like remove an app or rotate its keys. I was told that if SP has "Application administrator" role then it should have enough permissions to do so.

So how would I be able to achieve this in Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureaddirectoryrolemember?view=azureadps-2.0) PowerShell cmdlet.

Here is an example:

```
# Fetch role instance
$role = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq 'Application Administrator'}

# If role instance does not exist, instantiate it based on the role template
if ($role -eq $null) {
    # Instantiate an instance of the role template
    $roleTemplate = Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleTemplate | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq 'Application Administrator'}
    Enable-AzureADDirectoryRole -RoleTemplateId $roleTemplate.ObjectId

    # Fetch role
    $role = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq 'Application Administrator'}
}

# Add the SP to role
Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId  -RefObjectId <ObjectID of your SP>
```

Comment: "Get-AzureADDirectoryRole" command has returned 4 roles only - "Directory Readers", "Device Managers", " Directory Writers", "Company Administrator". No "Application Administrator".

Comment: Then you have to enable the AzureAdDirectory Role first. I edited my answer and fixed the link to the documentation (where you will find additional information).

Comment: Nice! It's worked out! One thing though, please, fix your answer by adding a missing single quote around Application Administrator. Thank you!