# Insufficient privileges to deploy Azure Service Principal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, service-principal, azure-service-principal

I'm a Microsoft employee and I'm new to Azure. I would like to deploy a Service Principal on my internal Microsoft Azure subscription. Using the Azure CLI, when I run

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name $spn_name
```

I get the error "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." The documentation here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) makes it seem like I don't have Azure Active Directory configured properly.

I don't have Azure Active Directory on my internal subscription. Do I need to add this? If so, how can I set this up on my Microsoft internal account? Is there a way to create a Service Principal without Azure Active Directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue was that my SP name was not unique. Changing the name solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Normal user without Admin roles also will be able to create a service principle even with Azure CLI. If the scenario is that you are creating a service principle from an application then you need application permissions. Please go through [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52285608/azure-service-principal-insufficient-permissions-to-manage-other-service-princip) which helps in fixing your issue.

Comment: Having to involve global admins for something like creating a service principal for an Azure DevOps service connection is such major PITA - I wish there was some way to create a subscription-local identity/service principal

Comment: Hi @Cocowalla,I don't have idea on devops scenario but please go through my updated answer.

Comment: The question you linked to is about assigning permissions to a service principal, rather than what permissions developers need to create the service principal in the first place?

Comment: ForUser level, there is no permissions needed.Admin should enable user can register an app as mentioned by Carl Zhao

Comment: Yes, but "user can register an app" *is* a permission! And the problem is that it's enabled for everyone or no one, so enterprises don't like to use it

Comment: I agree, but this error is commonly shown  for roles and API permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Does not require you to have administrator permissions.

If your account's **User type** is just a Member in the tenant. Make sure in the portal -> AAD -> User settings -> Users can register applications is Yes.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is a rather blunt instrument, so many organisations will not enable this

Comment: @Cocowalla   This is a must!

Comment: @Cocowalla  If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @Cocowalla  If you have any questions, please feel free to ask me, I will answer you as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm not the OP, I'm just some random having a rant about how *horribly* inconvenient Azure's permissions model is for access to create/edit AAD app registrations/principals :)

Comment: @Cocowalla   Oh, sorry :).